# Paginated Reports in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, power-bi-report-server

We're currently developing Power BI dashboards using Power  BI Desktop and Power BI Server for hosting. At the same time we have SSRS reports hosted on SSRS server. We now would like to add Power BI paginated reports as it has richer graphic features comparing to SSRS.  So I've got questions about Power BI Reports:

1. For hosting, do we need to install separate Power BI Report Server or Power BI Server that currently hosts dashboards can be re-used?
2. For developing reports, can Power BI Desktop be used for paginated reports' creation or additional software needs to be installed?
3. What is file extension for paginated reports - pbix (like Power BI dashboards) or rdl (like SSRS reports)?
4. Can Power BI Reports be hosted by SSRS server?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

I think I can help on a few of these points:

1. No, you host them in a workspace and or App on your server.  But you need to user Premium Per User License.
2. Download and install Power BI Paginated Report Builder:
   [PBI Report Builder](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8af52da3-1099-4e32-a868-931922842430)
3. It creates RDL files.
4. I'm not sure but I think they should be able to as I think they both produce RDL files.  Please feel free to correct.

Hope this helps.